# Need understanding on the HTML code which changes on click

Tags: html, wordpress, disqus

I am using WordPress. And installed Disqus plugin. So in the plugin settings of the Disqus plugin I've found the following:

```
<p>
<a class="button" href="#">Sync Comments</a>
This will download your Disqus comments and store them locally in WordPress
</p>
```

css of button

```
.wp-core-ui p .button {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.wp-core-ui .button, .wp-core-ui .button-secondary {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    color: #555555;
}
.wp-core-ui .button, .wp-core-ui .button-primary, .wp-core-ui .button-secondary {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

When I click on this, the code changed to

```
<div id="dsq_import">
<p class="status dsq-importing" rel="1575183395">Import in progress (last post id: 1575183395) …</p>
</div>
```

How did this happen? I have Firebug on Firefox. I want to know what code is being called after I click. Any Firebug tips to track these events?

Comment: I don't think CSS is doing that - any javascript? Oh you edited, nevermind...

Comment: this may be done by jquery.. check the jquery if any function defined

Comment: But anything specific which can be directly seen from the code itself. For what should i dig more. About the class button, whether it is assigned onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about investigating this and both will provide different information, depends on what you are looking for.

If you just want to know what javascript is being called, you can use the javascript tab which is explained here:

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

If you are interested in the data itself, the net tab will provide what was sent remotely, and what the response was.

http://getfirebug.com/network

The [firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) also has a wealth of knowledge under the panels section.

Comment: i am looking something more direct from the html code

Comment: If you are looking for something in the code directly then it should be in the HTML panel, but the code is changing as you describe because of javascript.

Comment: so how to know where to start looking from the code.

Comment: Well from what you describe, there is a javascript click event happening which changes the html.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Sync Comments</a>
        This will download your Disqus comments and store them locally in WordPress
    </p>    
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".button").on("click", function(){
/*
         Add your code to start the importing process 
         ...
         ...
*/  
                var p = $(this).parent("p");
                p.replaceWith('<div id="dsq_import"><p class="status dsq-importing" rel="1575183395">Import in progress (last post id: 1575183395)</p></div>');
            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code you are looking for should be using a similar idea.